# How to fix button at bottom despite of scroll in Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android, have linear layout and scroll inside it. I want my Button to be fixed at bottom even when scroll happens, not sure how to do that. Below is my code and button is at the last. Can someone help. I tried "android_gravity" and "layout_bottom=true" which i read in few answers in stackoverflow that I should be using them when I am using LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription|MissingPrefix">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"            
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/registration_string"
                android:textColor="@color/eula_body_text_color"
                android:textSize="19sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tool_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/tool_border_color" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/registration_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/profileFocus"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addPictureImageLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/addPictureImage"
                    android:layout_width="140dip"
                    android:layout_height="140dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="22.5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/uploadidphoto"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagephotorequired"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_11sdp"
                android:text="@string/image_photo_required"
                android:textColor="#ffe7181c"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_view2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_110sdp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_32sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_2sdp">

                <com.honeywell.hbs.visitormanagement.utils.CircleImage
                    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_87sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_87sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <!--  <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/vectorText"

                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:text="@string/registrationDetails"
                  android:textColor="@color/gray606060"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
  -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameText"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_11sdp"
                android:text="@string/first_name"
                android:textColor="@color/blackText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addIdProofPictureImageLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/id_proof_document"
                    android:layout_width="140dip"
                    android:layout_height="140dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/uploadidproof"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_proof_number_tv"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="@string/id_proof_number"
                android:textColor="@color/blackText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/id_proof_number"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_34sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:maxLength="4"

                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/asterix"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/proofnumberrequired"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_11sdp"
                android:text="@string/proofnumber_required"
                android:textColor="#ffe7181c"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_proof_type_tv"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="@string/id_proof_type"
                android:textColor="@color/blackText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/id_proof_type"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_34sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"

                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/asterix"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prooftyperequired"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_11sdp"
                android:text="@string/prooftype_required"
                android:textColor="#ffe7181c"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp" />

            <!--<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/id_proof_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_below="@+id/idProofcard_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:entries="@array/id_proof_type"
                android:popupBackground="#FFF"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/id_proof_spinner"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:background="#ffa0a0a0" />-->


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"

                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_34sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_state"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/confirm"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want btn_login fixed?

Comment: @SubhechhuKhanal - Yes

Comment: `I tried "android_gravity"` but you didn't try `"android:layout_gravity"`